# How to setup development mode for Eclipse GWT-Maven project?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, maven, development-mode

I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Win XP with Java 6.  I have Maven 3.0.3 and have a GWT (2.1) project, which I have imported into Eclipse.  How do I create a run configuration that will run the GWT project in develpoment mode?  I tried a run configuration with these goals:

```
clean gwt:run
```

But this fails to run in debug mode, since my breakpoint immediately upon entering the "onModuleLoad" method never gets triggered.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_with_maven ?

Follow the "if you'really not able to use Eclipse for Java EE" steps for best experience.

Answer (score 0):

You should run it with:

`gwt:debug`

For more information about goals check [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html).